# Search for Room Availability in Bookings [PHP/MySQL]

Tags: php, mysql

I am programming a Hotel Reservation module. Now I have to connect an existing application to get the available rooms on a given range of dates. Please help me in this.

I am here posting the DB schema of the existing app (where the rooms and bookings info were stored).

**rooms:**

```
id
room_type
room_count
people
hotel_id
```

**bookings:**

```
id
from
to
name
email
people
dt
hotel_id
```

**bookings_rooms**

```
booking_id
room_id
quantity
```

I will give 3 inputs

1. Hotel ID
2. From Date
3. To Date

What I need is a list of `room_id` and `max_qty_available`

Comment: Have you already tried some queries? If so, which queries?

Comment: Is switching room allowed? e.g. from/to is 7 nights, satisfiable by first 3 nights in room X, next 4 nights in room Y.

Comment: @Bas van Dorst: I haven't tried any queries. I am planning to write multiple queries and writing many for loops in PHP.

Comment: @Wrikken: Switching not allowed. I guess you got the flow :)

Comment: Well, I get if if you're not searching for min_qty_available, and rooms are possibly shared (more the hostel variant)? Or aren't they? What does this `max_qty_available` mean in that case: total numbers of room, total 'people' (which I assume is the number of beds / people allowed in a room), what?

Comment: @Wrikken: Sorry for the delay. A hotel may have `n` type of rooms. They may have `x` rooms in each type. That is the total is having `n`*`x` rooms. So I want to know what are all the room types available and in each room type how many rooms are available.

Comment: Ah, so `quantity` in `bookings_rooms` is _"how many rooms of that type are booked in this booking"_ ? Does clear up a few things...

Answer (score 1):

So, rooms aren't actually rooms, they are a type with a count. Does clear up a few things, although by rooms not being seperate entities it is very hard to prevent a change of rooms being eligable.

```
SELECT r.id, r.room_count  - SUM(br.quantity ) AS max_qty_available
FROM rooms r
LEFT JOIN bookings b
ON b.hotel_id = r.hotel_id
    AND b.from < <Date END>
    AND b.to   > <Date START>         
LEFT JOIN booking_rooms br
ON br.room_id = r.id 
    AND br.booking_id = br.id
WHERE r.hotel_id = <Hotel ID>
```

Answer (score 0):

I`m guessing what some of this parameters are, but here it goes:

Select id as room_id, room_Count as max_qty_available From Rooms Where
id Not in (Select room_id From Bookings_rooms Where booking_id
In (Select id From bookings Where from>=@FromDate And to <=@ToDate And hotel_id=@HotelID)
) And hotel_id = @HotelID

You can replace IN and NOT IN with Exists and Not exists if there is a performance issue. But not sure if Exists are supported in mysql.